# How to create an entrySet() method in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how to implement the entrySet() method inside my HashMapOpen class. HashMapOpen class is a class that represents a hash table uses open addressing, which implements Map interface. Hash table is represented as an array of Entry object,

```
Entry<K,V>[] data = new Entry[5].
```

Entry class implements

```
Map.Entry<K,V> and has 2 variables: K key and V value.
```

Entry class contains constructor Entry(K key, V value), getter and setter methods for key and value, toString() method, which returns a string as follow

```
<19, Tarzan> or <key,value>
```

and override the equals(Object obj) method.

HashMapOpen has 3 private variables:

```
private Entry<K, V>[] data = new Entry[5];
private final Entry<K, V> DELETED = new Entry(null, null);
private int size = 0;
```

The HashMapOpen has methods as follow:

```
// Get the value by using the key, return null if the key is not present  
     V get(K key);

// Check if the Map empty or not. Return True if the map contains no key-value set
     boolean isEmpty();

// Add the value to the map with its associated key, return the previous value, return null if there
// was no mapping for the key
     V put(K key, V value);

// Remove the mapping for this key, return the previous value, return null if there is no mapping for this key
     V remove(K key);

// Return the size of the key
     int size();

// toString method which returns a string represent the entry such as 

[0] - <15, Johnson>
[1] - null
[2] - <12, Carry>
...
     String toString();
```

After that I am trying to add the entrySet() method. Method entrySet creates a set view of the entries in Map. This means that method entrySet returns an object that implements the Set interface - that is, a set.

For example if in main method I said:

```
HashMapOpen<Integer,String> map = new HashMapOpen<>();
    map.put(24,"D");
    map.put(15,"A");
    map.put(46,"B");
    map.put(31,"C");

    Set<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> test = map.entrySet();
    System.out.print("Initial Value Key Set: " );
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> e: test) 
        System.out.println(e);
```

I will expect the output to be something close like this:

```
Initial Value Key Set: <15, A> <46,B> <31, C> <24,D>
```

Here is my code for entrySet() method:

/*This is a special section of code which I use to test out some features of Java
entrySet method return a view of the entries in a Map through Set implementation
*/

```
public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet(){
        return new EntrySet(); // Return a class ??? Uhm! interesting...
                               // One explanation is that the EntrySet class implements iterator method
                               // which is almost the same way of use as toString method, which means that
                               // no need to use reference.method to run, only need reference.
    }

    // AbstractSet provides a complete implementation of the Set interface except for the size and iterator methods
    private class EntrySet extends AbstractSet<Map.Entry<K,V>>{

        public int size(){
            return size;
        }

        public Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> iterator(){
            return new SetIterator();
        }
    }

    private class SetIterator implements Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>>{
        private Entry<K,V> next; // Next entry to return
        private int lastItemReturned; // Index of the current entry
        private Entry<K,V> current; // Current Entry

        public SetIterator(){
            if(size > 0){
                Entry<K,V>[] table = data;
                while(lastItemReturned < table.length && (next = data[lastItemReturned++]) == null)
                    ;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return next != null;
        }

        @Override
        public java.util.Map.Entry<K, V> next() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(next == null)
                throw new NoSuchElementException();

            Entry<K,V>[] table = data;
            Entry<K,V> e = table[lastItemReturned + 1];

            if((next = e) == null){
                while(lastItemReturned < table.length && (next = table[lastItemReturned++]) == null)
                    ;
            }
            current = e;
            return e;
        }

        public void remove(){

        }
    }
```

When I run the program or my main method, it keep printing

```
<15, A>
<15, A>
<15, A>
<15, A>
...
```

Comment: If you want to return a view, I think you will need to implement more methods... You should *adapt* the returned view to the underlying array of entries, so that i.e. if an entry is removed from the view, then it's also removed from the map.

Comment: You've got the right direction.  You need to make a new class extending `AbstractSet` and return an instance of it.  Your iterator implementation is just wrong.  It's probably more complicated than it has to be, too; you're copying local variables, doing things like `(next = e)` inline, and just making things more complicated than they probably need to be.

Comment: Thank you,  Federico Peralta Schaffner and Louis Wasserman for your comments. I am aware of the remove method you mentioned and will implement it later on; however, I am trying to focus on the iterator method as Louis Wasserman mentioned by implementing the Iterator<K,V> interface and override two of its classes, which are next() and hasNext()

Comment: I figure out the problem in the `java.util.Map.Entry<K, V> next()` method. Instead of put  **Entry<K,V> e = table[lastItemReturned + 1];** I should put **Entry<K,V> e = next** above first if statement to store the value of entry next and return its value. I also replace entry **next** in the 1st if statement with **e**.  I create another `Entry<K,V> current = table[lastItemReturned + 1]` as a replacement for **Entry<K,V> e = table[lastItemReturned + 1];**.

Comment: And in the second if statement I replace **e** with entry **current**, and add a else statement to increase the index of the array, **lastItemReturned**